# Invalid Picture In Visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I am developing a proj in vb 6. what the problems is that when i load icons(extension .ico) it gives "Invalid Picture". I searched it out on all the forums but still lying in. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
Image1.picture = loadpicture(app.path & "\Abc.ico")
```

But when convert the file to jpg from ico format :

```
image1.picture = loadpicture(app.path & "\Abc.jpg")
```

It is loaded to Image1.

i have also converted the icon file it to 24 bit from 32 bit but still is not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the specifics. Posting it in a comment means people can't see it when they read your question. Thanks. Is `Abc.ico` a valid Windows icon? Not PNG, but old-style Windows icon - VB6 is *old*, and doesn't support alpha-blended or high-color icons; it expects old format, dull icons like in the Windows 95 days.

Comment: You actually said (in a previous comment) "when I change picture *name*"; you didn't say "When I use a different picture file". You have an invalid icon file. As I said, VB6 is *old*, and expects .ico files to be the old Win95 format, not the newer alpha-blended Vista/Win7 icons.

Comment: @KenWhite - I love your real world examples!

Comment: Once again, *you have an invalid icon file*. VB6 wants old-style, 32x32, 256 color Win95-type icons, and the one you're trying to load apparently isn't one. As we don't have a copy of the icon file to examine, it's pretty much impossible to explain anything else.

Answer (score 4):

Your icon is probably a 32bit icon- it just needs to be changed to 24bit in order for it to be supported in VB6. You can use a program like IcoFX to change the bit depth.

Comment: This error occurs when running VB6 on Windows 8.1 with a form where the icon file had two formats, 32x32 at 4 bit and 16x16 at 4 bit. Adding a 32x32 at 24 bit resolved the issue, so there must be a minimum bit depth for Windows 8.1 (which is greater than required by Windows 7).

Comment: Yes the @VictorMcManus answer is correct, also VB6 doesn't support the size 256x256.

Answer (score 1):

You must create your icon file using a generator that actually saves it as an .ICO. You cant try to take a jpg or png and re-save it as an .ico file.

Comment: Try this link: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=create%20vb6%20icon&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQtwIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D64udz7aNvX4&ei=GFDDUbumDafGywH65oCABg&usg=AFQjCNGQn5x6UukSxOPbE22_QXwuGWrfdQ&bvm=bv.48175248,d.aWc

Comment: my dears i haven't changed the jpg,bmp,png or other files to ico.

Comment: I have just downloaded .ico files from web and want to place it in my design interface. But it gives err.

Comment: they need to be very simplified ico's for VB6

Comment: so i don't know from where i can get simplified ico's.Someone has told me in our Softhouse that it might be caused by using 32 bit ico's,change it to 24 bit. i did so but so far i m lying in.

Comment: Try this link as well... it has some links on how they need to be created. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?611547-How-to-create-an-icon-that-VB6-accepts

Comment: tnx logixologist i try it.

Comment: yes i checked it out but it still my problem is. I think i might not be the problem of lower and higer bits i mean(16x16,32x32).

Answer (score 1):

In VB6 Icons (*.ICO) can only be used to be set as icons wherever applicable. You can use *.ico file for the application's main window.

But the image1.picture can't have an icon loaded with the loadpicture method.

Comment: How can an icon be loaded as a picture? Is there even a way?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to load pictures of almost any format I recommend you using FreeImage (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/).

You need to copy FreeImage.dll to the Windows\System32 folder and then include their bas module into your VB6 project.  Once you do that you can load an icon simply into your image:

```
Image1.Picture = LoadPictureEx(App.Path & "\Abc.ico")
```

Answer (score 0):

Once i got this error when the C: drive had zero bytes free. After cleaning some space the error gone.

Comment: Correct. It's a cause for the "invalid picture" error at runtime.